# Joining Nurbs Circles?

Tags: nurbs-surface

I was trying to do this simple [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kGmh9r6pkE) but when I tried to join the circles these just smashed into one and I can't even move them along the z axys.
Thanks in advance!.

EDIT: Adding de blend file, sorry fot the wait [image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: You want to join all the circle if so. Make a single nurb and in edit mode make all the circle nurb and select all the nurb and then press F key